# absolute url not able to put before dot operator in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an application in react. But the images are not rendering.
The json response of the image is

"thumbnail": "/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/gsh020_shoes/200x310/gsh020_2001.jpg"

What I have implemented in code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


import axios from 'axios';

class PLPMenu extends Component {

  state = {
    shoeCategory: []
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'GirlShoeCategory'



    axios.get(`http://localhost:3030/${url}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express.catalogEntryView);
        this.setState({
          shoeCategory: res.data.express.catalogEntryView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {
    const { shoeCategory } = this.state;
    const picUrl = 'https://149.129.128.3:8443'

    return (

      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {
              shoeCategory.map(shoeList => (

                <div className="col-md-4">

                  <h2 key={shoeList.uniqueID}></h2>


                  <img src={shoeList + picUrl + .thumbnail}/>
                  <Link to="/PDP"><p className="pdp">{shoeList.name}</p></Link>
                  <p>{shoeList.price[0].value}</p>


                </div>

              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>




    )

  }

}

export default PLPMenu;
```

In the code above, under the map function, I have implemented {shoeList.thumbnail}. But, the images are not rendering. It needs to add the absolute path before the thumbnail which I'm unable to implement. Can somebody please help me in this how to concatenate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the full path to your image is:

`https://149.129.128.3:8443/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/gsh020_shoes/200x310/gsh020_2001.jpg`

and assuming `shoeList` is an object

you are trying to make an url that looks something like:

`[object Object]https://149.129.128.3:8443/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/gsh020_shoes/200x310/gsh020_2001.jpg`

The following fix might be what you're after judging by your description:

```
<img src={picUrl + shoeList.thumbnail} />
```

which should resolve to make the source be `https://149.129.128.3:8443/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/apparel/girls/gsh020_shoes/200x310/gsh020_2001.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure if I understand you correctly but you could use templating string for concatenation.

For example:

```
const imageSrc = `${picUrl}${shoeList}${shoeList.thumbnail}`
```

Hope this can help you out.

Cheers

Comment: But I got it.....But, can't it be done before {shoeList.thumbnail} using a variable const picUrl = "https://149.129.128.3:8443" and concatenate